# Triggers Based on Properties from DataContext

Tags: wpf, triggers

Suppose I want to show/hide elements based on Values of Properties from DataContext, how can I acheive it?

```
// In MainWindow.xaml.cs: DataContext of MainWindow.xaml
public int Mode { get; set; }
```

In XAML, I want to show hide elements based on the `Mode`. How can I make the below work? Or what is the appropriate way of implementing this?

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Mode" Value="1">
            <Setter TargetName="txt1" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Setter TargetName="txt2" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter TargetName="txt3" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Mode" Value="2">
            <Setter TargetName="txt1" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter TargetName="txt2" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Setter TargetName="txt3" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>
    <TextBlock Text="TextBlock 1" x:Name="txt1" />
    <TextBlock Text="TextBlock 2" x:Name="txt2" />
    <TextBlock Text="TextBlock 3" x:Name="txt3" />
</StackPanel>
```

Currently, the Error I am getting is "*Property 'Mode' was not found in type 'StackPanel'.  D:\tmp\WpfApplication1\TriggersAndProperties\MainWindow.xaml*"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `DataTriggers` if you want triggers that can work on bindings. Problem is, `DataTriggers` are only available on style and template so you need to define one like this:

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Mode}" Value="1">
          <Setter TargetName="txt1" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
          <Setter TargetName="txt2" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
          <Setter TargetName="txt3" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Mode}" Value="2">
          <Setter TargetName="txt1" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
          <Setter TargetName="txt2" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
          <Setter TargetName="txt3" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </StackPanel.Style>
  <TextBlock Text="TextBlock 1" x:Name="txt1" />
  <TextBlock Text="TextBlock 2" x:Name="txt2" />
  <TextBlock Text="TextBlock 3" x:Name="txt3" />
</StackPanel>
```

Another solution would be to use an `IValueConverter` that converts the int from `Mode` to the `Visibility` you want, and apply it directly to each text block `Visibility` property.

Note that Dean Chalk's answer stays valid: you have to use a `DependencyProperty` or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you want changes on `Mode` to trigger.

Comment: Got compilation error MC4011: TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter

Comment: Your example doesn't work. "The name 'txt1' is not recognized.

Answer (score 2):

Your propert 'Mode' needs to be a dependency property in order to be used this way:

```
public class MainViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    readonly DependencyProperty ModeProperty = DependencyProperty
        .Register("Mode", typeof(int), typeof(MainViewModel));

    public int Mode
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(ModeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ModeProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i have a multitrigger where one condition is a datatrigger ? and was is a ui-element property ?